# I want to put a touch event to start my game

Tags: java, android

Does anybody know what code I should use to make my android game start on a touch event ? I tried looking at tutorials but I don't get it because I am not used to Java.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) {
    startgame;
    return false;
}
```

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
tools:context=".MainActivity" android:background="@drawable/start" 
android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false" android:id="@+id/"> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What kind of game is this? Desktop application, mobile app...etc? We need a lot more details about what you want to do.

Comment: and delete `xml` tag

Comment: If this is android there might be xml. @Brandon T -  What is this?

Comment: oh sorry for not being specific , this is a android sdk game im trying to create

Comment: Im trying to create for the google play store

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/start"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
    android:id="@+id/">

</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

If this is in swing, you could use a MouseListener.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.awt.event.*;

...

In some method-
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()){
    public void mouseClicked(){
         //code here
    }
    public void mouseEntered(){
         //code here
    }
    public void mouseExited(){
         //code here
    }
    public void mouseReleased(){
         //code here
    }
    public void mousePressed(){
         //code here
    }
 }
```

panel is the jPanel

EDIT: Nevermind. The OP said he was making an android app

Comment: what is `add` method?

Comment: `JPanel.add()` accepts a `Component`. It should be `panel.addMouseListener()`

Comment: this is a android game and i want it to take the user to the game when they touch the screen

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `@Override` annotation to your method?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) {
    startgame; 
    return false; 
}
```

If you haven't, this method would never be called by the system.

**EDIT:**

You may be looking for the onUserInteraction to start it. See code below:

```
boolean gameHasStarted = false;

@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    if (! gameHasStarted) {
        gameHasStarted = true;
        startGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it to start the game when the user clicks the screen . Do you kno wwhat will do this ?

Comment: Ok, got it. I'll edit my answer soon, I know what you mean now

Comment: Sorry for the late edit. Maybe that is what you needed.